# Can't auto set "Group directories" (dired-quick-sort) when start Emacs

Tags: dired

Linux Mint 20.1

Emacs 26.3

Install package:

```
(require 'dired-quick-sort)
(dired-quick-sort-setup)
```

https://github.com/emacsmirror/dired-quick-sort

And I want to show first directories in dired mode. To do this I press **S** and select **Group directories** = **yes (g)**.

And here result.

[image]

Nice. It's work correct. But the problem is... when I restart Emacs I need AGAIN to set this sort manually.

Is it possible to autoset this sort (by **Group directories**) when start Emacs?

Comment: Doesn't the doc of that package tell you how to do it?

Comment: @Drew Put this in init.el and success save sort after reset Emacs: (savehist-mode 1)

Comment: I don't understand. In any case, please put all relevant info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Q & A need to stand on their own, including to be searchable by search engines etc.